# IndexError in retrieving data from xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

```
<ENTITY>
    <ENTITY_ADDRESS>
        <CITY> Pyongyang </CITY>
        <COUNTRY > Democratic People's Republic of Korea</COUNTRY>
    </ENTITY_ADDRESS>
</ENTITY>
```

I am trying to get the city from the above xml document using python built-in module xml. The code is give bellow:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml = minidom.parse('data.xml')

entities = xml.getElementsByTagName('ENTITY')

city = entities[0].getElementsByTagName("CITY")[0].firstChild.data
```

But I am getting this error:

```
File "G:/Sakib/Scrapy/xml_to_json/xml_to_json.py", line 4, in <module>
    city = entities[0].getElementsByTagName("CITY")[0].firstChild.data
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed out `ENTITY_ADDRESS`. Also you should be able to call `nodeValue` to get the text.

Try:

```
    from xml.dom import minidom

    xml = minidom.parse('data.xml')
    
    entities = xml.getElementsByTagName('ENTITY')

    entities_address = entities[0].getElementsByTagName('ENTITY_ADDRESS')

    city = entities_address[0].getElementsByTagName("CITY")[0].firstChild.nodeValue.strip()
```

Also you can just shorten the code by searching for `CITY` only:

```
xml = minidom.parse('data.xml')
city = xml.getElementsByTagName("CITY")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
print(city.strip())
```

Output:

```
Pyongyang
```

Comment: It says:
AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: Sorry slight typo, I've updated the answer